Anyway I can make layers colorful in PS
I am wondering is there any way I can make a bunch of layers colorful in PS. I mean can I assign color to a bunch of layers? Like I can do in AI. I mean, suppose, the layers those are associated with flowers illustration I make them red in layer panel, The layers associated with hand I make them blue, just to know which layers belng to which artwork. all are grey in layer panel. I lose track.
Thank you.


Right-click/Control-click highlighted layers... pick a color.
It's actually a bit better in Photoshop than it is Illustrator. The colors are more apparent in Photoshop as well as being a bit easier to access.
And if you assign a color to a Group, all layers within that group take on that color.


:O :o :O oh gawwd!!! This is doable!!! :O :O :O OH my gawwd!!! am dead. am so happy that am actually dead!! Thank you so much.
